# laravel 5 Мультидоменная аутентификация

Tags: laravel, аутентификация

Как аутентифицировать пользователя сразу на всех поддоменах главного домена, поискал в нете написано что надо использовать базу данных в качестве хранилки сессий и указать в конфиге сессиии

```
.aproject.com
```

, но почему то не работает, когда так делаю аутентификация вообще не проходит даже на основном домене.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для 5.2 проверьте файл *.env* - укажите там `SESSION_DRIVER=database`.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете последнюю версию - убедитесь что все ваши routes сгрупировани под middleware `web`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function($route){});
```